# Awakening a sleeping thread with SSE eventSource listener

Tags: java, multithreading, server-sent-events

I have a multithreaded application. Each thread is supposed to listen to streaming data and process events from stream.

The run() method currently looks like this :

```
public void run() {

    Client client ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(SseFeature.class).build();
    WebTarget target = client.target("https://stream.example.com/");

    org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventSource eventSource = 
            new org.glassfish.jersey.media.sse.EventSource(target) {

        @Override
        public void onEvent(InboundEvent inboundEvent) {
            System.out.println(inboundEvent.getName()+ " :: " + threadId);

            ...

        }
    };


    while (true) {

        try{
            Thread.sleep(500L); 
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            ...
        }           
    }
}
```

What I would like to accomplish is that thread sleeps as much as possible and will be awaken only when an event arrives in the stream. That way majority of my threads can sleep and avoid cpu load. I am not confident that when the thread is sleeping using Thread.sleep(), is awaken by the event. After all, eventSource listener is in the same thread that was put to sleep.

So my question in essence is that Is there way that eventSource can awaken the thread ?

Answer (score 0):

Following seems to have done the trick .. as eventInput.read() should block untill there is something to read.

```
public void run() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(SseFeature.class).build();
    WebTarget target = client.target("https://stream.example.com/");

    EventInput eventInput = target.request().get(EventInput.class);
    while (!eventInput.isClosed()) {
        final InboundEvent inboundEvent = eventInput.read();
        if (inboundEvent == null) {
            // connection has been closed
            break;
        }

        onEvent(inboundEvent);          
    }
}

protected void onEvent(InboundEvent inboundEvent) {
     ....
}
```